# Add like button to Facebook page - what's the appid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Say I have the website http://www.example.org and the corresponding Facebook page at http://www.facebook.com/example.

When I now try to generate a [**Like-Box**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) (or a Like Button) an **AppId** is required. Creating an Application via Facebook Developer seems not like what I want - all I want is the button?

How do I create that like button / like-box for my website example.org (what are the simplest steps)?

Comment: I just generated a `like` button without being prompted for an **AppId** from the link you posted. I wasn't logged in or anything if that helps?

Comment: That helps. I actually **was** logged in, which meant that I **had** to choose an AppId from one of my private test apps which are completely unrelated to the websites. Being logged out is pretty much the simple solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the simplest step is here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Further, the facebook page `facebook.com/example` and `example.org` are completely indipendent (like-button-wise). So if you want to have a like button for your *facebook-page*, you can use the link to facebook or even generate a [like-box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)!

Other than that, you *can* initialize the fb api with an *optional* fb-app and its id. You probably found out already where to do that ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)). With that you have access to `insights`, which are statistics for your like button. There are also further uses for it when playing around with the FB API or plugins like the comment-box. But you don't have to have an app-id to run the like button on your page!

Comment: Ah! So if I would want **insights** - would I just go ahead and create an empty app for like button?

Comment: It's not really empty, because you automatically let it connect to your web-application (your like-button), so it stands for itself. But yes, just create an app and enter its ID on your homepage! In the meanwhile, there were also other ways created like [this here](http://www.wisnet.com/blog/using-facebook-insights-to-track-the-like-button-box-and-shares/)